# amsart header - don't display author name

Tags: amsart

How can I achieve that in the `amsart` documentclass, only the document title is displayed in the header? By default the header alternates between the author name and document title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `\markboth{\shorttitle}{\shorttitle}` after `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\markboth{\shorttitle}{\shorttitle}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```